# Precise timing with serial write

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

The code below sends a character over serial and waits 8 ms.

```
import serial
import time
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial(
  port='/dev/cu.usbserial-AD01ST7I',\
  writeTimeout = 0,\
  baudrate=115200,\
  parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
  bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
)

for z in range(5000):
  ser.write('C')
  time.sleep(.008)
```

Measuring the serial activity on the serial port with a scope shows that the message is sent every ~10 ms. It varies a little – sometimes the interval is 8.5 ms.

[Oscilloscope measurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jycb.png)

Is there a way to send the message precisely every 8ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, unless you use [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). There are many factors that will affect the precision:

- Serial buffering. You can force to write the data immediately by calling `flush`
- Timer accuracy, which is different on each OS. Sometimes in the order of milliseconds.
- OS scheduling, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)